# Python - Use multiple str.startswith() in a for loop get their specific values

Tags: python, string, csv, startswith

The below function parses multiple csv files in a directory and takes out values using str.startwith().

It works find using '*firstline.startswith('TrakPro')*' and '`txt.startswith('Serial')`'. However, when I add a third str.startwith() i.e. txt2.startswith('Test'), nothing prints out, no error, appears to ignore it. What do I need to change? Basically I want to add multiple str.startwith() in the for loop pulling out various key words after the ':".

```
def get_csv_file_list(root):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(root):
        for file in f:

            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                path = os.path.join(r, file)
                dir_name = path.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
                file_name = os.path.basename(file)

                try:
                    with open(path) as k:
                        firstline = k.readline()

                        if firstline.startswith('TrakPro'):
                            file_list.append(path)
                            file_list.append(dir_name)
                            file_list.append(file_name)

                            txt = 'Serial Number:'
                            if txt.startswith('Serial'):
                                for row in list(k)[3:4]:
                                    file_list.append(row[15:26])

                            txt2 = 'Test Name:'
                            if txt2.startswith('Test'):
                                for rows in list(k)[4:5]:
                                    print(rows)
                                    file_list.append(row[11:])
```

The csv looks like this:

```
TrakPro Version 5.2.0.0 ASCII Data File
Instrument Name:,SidePak
Model Number:,TK0W02
Serial Number:,120k2136005
Test Name:,13270
Start Date:,04/17/2021
Start Time:,01:53:29
Duration (dd:hh:mm:ss):,00:07:13:00
Log Interval (mm:ss):,01:00
Number of points:,433
Description:,
```

So far I have tried the above code, I expected to print out values in the 'Test Name' line of the csv sample. The function does not print out anything, no error.

Tks

Comment: You are consuming `k` as you go. Each reference to a chunk of k moves the pointer forward by the size of the chunk, be it line or a list splice. You have not made allowances for that. Best test the first line, then consume all of `k` into a `list`, then check the parts you need to, allowing for the fact that the `list` contains all but the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print only the value of the line that starts with `Test Name:` you can use following code:

```py
with open("your_file.csv", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line.startswith("Test Name:"):
            _, value = line.split(",", maxsplit=1)
            print(value)
```

Prints:

```
13270
```

Comment: really wanted to know why a third if statement does not produce the desired result, but I adapted Andrej's method to make it work. tks

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you are consuming `k` as you go.

To see what is going on, run the following:

```
file_name = "./abc.csv"
file_list=[]
with open(file_name) as k:
    firstline = k.readline() # Consume first line
    if firstline.startswith('TrakPro'):
        print("First line:\n", firstline)
        file_list.append(file_name)
        txt = list(k) # here k is the file contents minus the first line
        print("Contents of list\n", txt)
        if str(txt[2]).startswith('Serial'):
            file_list.append(str(txt[2])[15:26])
        if str(txt[3]).startswith('Test'):
            file_list.append(str(txt[3].strip())[11:])
print("\nResult:\n",file_list)
```

Where the contents of abc.csv are:

```
TrakPro Version 5.2.0.0 ASCII Data File
Instrument Name:,SidePak
Model Number:,TK0W02
Serial Number:,120k2136005
Test Name:,13270
Start Date:,04/17/2021
Start Time:,01:53:29
Duration (dd:hh:mm:ss):,00:07:13:00
Log Interval (mm:ss):,01:00
Number of points:,433
Description:,
```

The result should be:

```
First line:
 TrakPro Version 5.2.0.0 ASCII Data File

Contents of list
 ['Instrument Name:,SidePak\n', 'Model Number:,TK0W02\n', 'Serial Number:,120k2136005\n', 'Test Name:,13270\n', 'Start Date:,04/17/2021\n', 'Start Time:,01:53:29\n', 'Duration (dd:hh:mm:ss):,00:07:13:00\n', 'Log Interval (mm:ss):,01:00\n', 'Number of points:,433\n', 'Description:,\n']

Result:
 ['./abc.csv', '120k2136005', '13270']
```